# CAKE PHP 3.6 setViewVars not passing variables to email template

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cake php 3.6 framework i'm trying to set up an email template.

The problem is that setViewVars is not passing variables to the view. Undefined variable: name is fired when rendering the view to all setViewVars keys.

```
$this->layout = '/email/html/default';
$enviar = 'Formulário de Franchising: ' . $name . '. Com o Email: ' . $email_add;
$emails = array('andre@dri.pt');
$email = new Email('default');
$email->from([$email_add => $email_add])
    ->template('default')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->setViewVars(['name'    => $name,
                   'email'   => $email_add,
                   'phone'   => $phone,
                   'company' => $company,
                   $emailcheck,
                   $smscheck,
                   'message' => $data['message']
    ])
    ->to($emails)
    ->subject('Subscrição Formulário.')
    ->send($enviar);
$this->Flash->success(__('Formulário Enviado. Obrigado!'));
return $this->render('/email/html/default');
```

Can not figured out the problem. Debbuging all variables in controller side they have the correct values.

**EDIT:**
In the view i tryed to echo with $this->variable_name and get a missing helper error. It says helper could not be found.

Comment: View variables aren't properties, but just regular variables, ie you access them like `$variableName`, not like `$this->variableName`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$this->variable_name`, you can directly access them using `variable_name` on your view

As per `Cakephp` Documentation:

You can set view variables with `Email::setViewViars():`

```
$email = new Email('templated');
$email->setViewVars(['value' => 12345]);
```

In your email templates you can use these with:

```
<p>Here is your value: <b><?= $value ?></b></p>
```

[Cakephp -> Email -> Sending Templated Emails](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails)